# repeating results using ajax and jquery javascripting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

Good day I want to make a a javascript via ajax that when I hover on a button 
it'll get its id and value then the value will be passed on a php script inside the same page used as a varible in searching which place I have selected

here is the javascript I tried

```
<script>


        function b1(a){




        $(".btn").hover(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'zone.php',
                data: {mapname: a.value},
                success: function(data){
                    document.write(data);
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btn").hover(function(){
                $("#box").toggle();
            });
        });
        }

    </script>
```

here are the buttons

```
    <div class="container">
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="ilocos" value="Ilocos" onmouseover="b1(this);" style="border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;">Ilocos</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="cagayan" value="Cagayan" onmouseover="b1(this)" style="border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;">Cagayan</button>
    </div>
```

then i have a div which i wanted to toggle when the button is hovered containing the php codes from the database

```
<div id="box">
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['mapname'])){

    }else{


    $tempmapnam = $_POST['mapname'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fsqm");
    $sql = "Select map_name, map_zh, map_zhc from tbl_map where map_name='".$tempmapnam."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)
        or die ("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        echo "<table class=\"table table-hover table-condensed\"><thead><th>Location</th><th>Zone Head</th><th>Contact</th></thead><tbody>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$row["map_name"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["map_zh"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["map_zhc"]."</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        echo "No Data found";
    }
    $con->close();

    }
?>
</div>
```

I just started javascript and ajax yesterday so please bear with me it actually works the problem is that it repeats the whole 2 divs inside the page

Comment: instead of doing this you can pass `json` object from php and use it in `success` callback

Comment: Do u want to make ajax call on one button or both buttons with button class, and where is the <div> that you are getting repeatedly?

Comment: Why is $("#box").toggle(); required?

Comment: @uzaif i'll look into i it I have no idea about jsons :/

Comment: @AfshanShujat whenever I hover at the two buttons it's like throwing the whole div starting from the div where buttons are to the empty div box where the php code is

Comment: @Teja I wanted to view database(div id="box") while the mouse is over the button then out so I can go to another button for another result

Comment: what you got in `data` it display in page?

Comment: the data contains the class of the button which are the name of places and which i used to select the specific places stored in the database and it works its just that i think it print's the whole 2 divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at following code. I dont have database thats why I used hard-coded values you can use there dynamic values. 
You have to check sequences of code executing, depending on that your code will be execute. You have to use exit() becuase we are using same page for ajax request. Use Jquery file path. First you have to take blank div "box" and ajax will return you response which will be dynamic (Values which are changing as per mapnames), that response should dump into div using jquery or you can use javascript also. You have to use only mysqli as per your mysql version

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function b1(a)
{    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'zone.php',
        data: {mapname: a.value,action:'getdata' },
        success: function(data){
            $('#box').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";
$dbname = "dbtest";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to database");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{    
    $tempmapnam = $_POST['mapname'];
    $sql = "Select map_name, map_zh, map_zhc from tbl_map where map_name='".$tempmapnam."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){        
        $out= "<div style=\"z-index: -1; width: 500px; height: 500px; posision: absolute; top: 0px;\"><table class=\"table table-hover table-condensed\"><thead><th>Location</th><th>Zone Head</th><th>Contact</th></thead><tbody>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $out.= "<tr>
            <td>".$row["map_name"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["map_zh"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["map_zhc"]."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        $out.=  "</tbody></table></div>";
        print $out;
        exit();
    }   
}
?>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="ilocos" value="Ilocos" onmouseover="b1(this);" style="border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;">Ilocos</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="cagayan" value="Cagayan" onmouseover="b1(this)" style="border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;">Cagayan</button>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering I was wondering how will the php code show inside the <div id="box"> when it is placed out side? :/

Comment: Could you expand what do you want to say, please ?  You can put your php code in "if case " if(isset($_POST['action']))  depending on mapname you can fetch record from database. is not my answer helpful to you ?

Comment: it actually didn't work, but I'm still studying your code I understand what you did although I have no idea why it didn't work :/

Comment: You have to change Jquery file path as per your folder structure, and php code which is fetching values from database. Or give me your database ,table structure and data, so I will implement it and provide you.

Comment: the Jquery file path is a link from bootstrap 3 I see no problems with that, please mail me @ markprincedecinal@gmail.com i'll reply you with the resources that you needed

Answer (score 0):

Replace `document.write(data);` with `$('#box').html(data);`.
Remove `$(".btn").hover` and `$(document).ready` handlers. You already have one powered by `onmouseover` attribute.
Result should be something like this:

```
function b1(a){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'zone.php',
        data: {mapname: a.value},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#box').html(data);
        }
    });

    $("#box").toggle();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't repeat again and again but only once and the toggle works although it toggles the whole 2 divs

Comment: @MarkPrinceLawrenceDecinal I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: dude I kinda got the logic of what you did, the toggle and everything worked the problem now though is that the div of the buttons also shows up with the toggle instead of the <div id="box"> only